# jQuery Mobile List Item Split Button without Link on main item

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Let's say I have a jQuery Mobile site with a bunch of `<li>` with a split icon (`data-icon="grid"`).

Is it possible to have the left-hand side of the list item not wrapped in a `href` but keep the button on the right-hand side?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SSQMB/

[image]

I have tried:

```
$(selection).contents().unwrap();
```

And this works, it removes the link as requested (and fixes the problem I've outlined below), but it goes and breaks a whole bunch of the layout and styling on the list item.

The issue I'm trying to resolve is this:

- I have about 100 `<li>` items on a page
- Each `<li>` might have a `<select>` element in it with 5-10 options.
- When using the default jQuery Mobile styling of a `<select>` everything works fine
- However this has a major performance hit. An iPhone 4S struggles to scroll, and an iPad 2 is virtually unusuable (Android is actually better for once, but still not perfect)
- Putting `data-role="none"` on the `<select>` elements makes the page fast and workable again
- However, it breaks on a desktop browser (Firefox in particular) because when you click to choose an item in the `<select>`, the link from behind the `<select>` is triggered and the `<select>` box is cancelled

Any ideas?

Comment: Well i tried to come up wth something but unfortunately couldnt find alternative way, well except if you write your own html-jquery-css code just for this..

Comment: @Efthimis - thanks :) If I do find a solution I will post it here. I suspect replicating the CSS styles might be the only solution.

Comment: @Efthimis - I found a way to do it. It's not too elegant, but it works. Posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after delving through the stock jQuery Mobile CSS, I found the styles that determine the formatting for the `<li>`. I duplicated these in a seperate stylesheet and made them apply to a `<span>` instead of an `<a>`:

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-text span.ui-link-inherit { text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;  }
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner span.ui-link-inherit { padding: .7em 15px .7em 15px; display: block; }
```

Then, set up the `<li>` as such:

```
<li data-icon="grid">
  <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="leftLink">
    <span class="ui-link-inherit">
      .... content ....
    </span>
  </a><a href="#"> ... </a>
</li>
```

Then some jQuery:

```
$('.leftLink').parent().parent().parent().removeClass('ui-btn');
$('.leftLink').contents().unwrap();
```

and Voila: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwhs3/2/

Comment: I also had tried something similar with the css styles but failed) anyway good job. :D